# Drupal 7.2: Horizontal & Vertical Tabs- HOW?

Tags: views

Using d7.2.  I'm looking to create this setup, possibly w/ JQuery (or something similar that would provide real time tabs w/o refreshing the page).

```
         Popular        Visits       Comments      Recent
```

Category 1

Category 2

Category 3

Category 4

So the user would click on one of the category tabs on the left side (vertical), and then they can sort w/ the links at the top w/ real-time refresh/results, no page refreshing or loading required.

I like the look of JQuery tabs- but want the best solution here. By best I mean easiest, lightest, and most compatible with most browsers.

I can setup various views to execute the searches/results- but do I make those 'pages', or 'blocks'? How do I create the tabs and links for sorting?

Thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best solution is using the [Quick Tabs module](http://drupal.org/project/quicktabs). It allows you to create static or dynamic Ajax loaded tabs with nodes, blocks, and views.

Comment: This seems to be a great solution, does vertical tabs AND nested tab/functions/links- all using JQuery. Awesome- thank you!

Comment: I just noticed that tabs can now be rendered in a jQuery UI accordion widget. Wow.

Comment: yes, this works great. I got it up and running quickly, and can do some powerful stuff using jquery ui.  Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Sadly QuickTabs doesn't work for dynamic views, 'triggered' by taxonomy (menu). If anyone has a suggestion for this issue - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34621/views-menu-tabs-with-a-dynamic-view-drupal-7-views-3?rq=1 -- getting no love, would appreciate.